# when i convert CSV file and saves it to database it saves data in database between " ",so how can i remove " "

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

This is my comma separated value file conversion code.

```
 string deliminator = ",";
 string tablename = "Converted";
        //string filelink = FileName.Text;
        string fileintro = FileName.Text;
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(fileintro.Trim());
        DS.Tables.Add(tablename);

    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("A");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("B");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("C");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("D");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("E");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("F");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("G");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("H");
    DS.Tables[tablename].Columns.Add("I");
```

...

```
SQLiteConnectionconn=newSQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString);           

SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand ("INSERT INTO ConvertData (a,b,c,d,e,f) values ('"+a+"'...), con);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                co.Close();
                FileName.Text = "";
   }
```

it saves data in database table like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" so how can i save it normally like 1,2,3,4,5,6,into database columns.'

Comment: You should show code that 1) can be compiled and 2) contains all necessary data. What are the datatypes of your columns? What is `a`? in your query? Show the complete query and all variables you are putting into it and how you construct them

Answer (score 0):

The data from comma separate files are exported as string. So before inserting into the database tables convert them into required data types. For examples, if the data type in the table is int, use the Parse function and convert the string to integer before inserting, You need to repeat this for all columns

```
int Id = Int32.Parse(ExcelCol1.Text);
```

If you are looking for a detailed approach, the below link will help you

[Uploading an Excel sheet and importing the data into SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447015/uploading-an-excel-sheet-and-importing-the-data-into-sql-server-database)

Comment: NO ACTUALLY PROBLEM IS conversion done completely but in database table first column nd last column save data like "A......Z"